# ResultSet to jTable = java.sql.SQLException: The prepared statement has been finalized

Tags: java, swing, sqlite, jdbc

Friends of StackOverFlow!

I Try "return" a ResultSet in select statement and have erros...
I Search in Google and StackOverFlow, but nothing Solve This Problem!

The Statement Insert Work OK! But the Select not Work...

**Database Layer:**

```
package Database;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class DBConnection {
    private static Connection               conn = null;
    private static ResultSet                rs = null;
    private static Statement                stmt = null;
    private static PreparedStatement        pst = null;

    private static final String             DATABASE_PATH_NAME="jdbc:sqlite:MiraReal.Xitano";

    private Connection Connect()
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");

            conn                            = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_PATH_NAME);

            return conn;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(DBConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

            return null;
        }
    }

    public boolean RunQuery(String sql)
    {
        Statement                           stmt;
        try {
            Connect();

            stmt                            = conn.createStatement();

            stmt.execute(sql);

            Disconnect();

            return true;

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DBConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            return false;
        }
        // create a new table
    }

    public ResultSet RunSelect(String sql){
        try {
            Connect();

            stmt                            = conn.createStatement();

            rs                              = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            //rs..moveToFirst();
            Disconnect();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DBConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return rs;
    }

    public int RunCount(String sql, String where)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    private void Disconnect()
    {
        try 
        {
            DBConnection.conn.close();
            DBConnection.conn               = null;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DBConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

**Actions Layer:**

```
package Actions;

import Models.CustomersModels;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class CustomersActions extends CustomersModels {
    protected String sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO customers (uuid, fullname, email, created_at, updated_at) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s') ";
    protected String sqlUpdate = "UPDATE customers SET fullname='%s' WHERE uuid='%s'";
    protected String sqlDelete = "DELETE FROM customers WHERE uuid='%s'";
    protected String sqlSelect = "SELECT %s FROM customers %s %s %s";

    public boolean insert()
    {
        String sql = String.format(sqlInsert, this.getUuid(), 
                this.getFullname(), this.getEmail(), this.getCreatedAt(), 
                this.getUpdatedAt());

        return this.RunQuery(sql);
    }

    public boolean update()
    {
        String sql = String.format(sqlUpdate, this.getFullname(), this.getUuid());

        return this.RunQuery(sql);
    }

    public boolean delete()
    {
        String sql = String.format(sqlDelete, this.getUuid());

        return this.RunQuery(sql);
    }

    public ResultSet select(String columns, String where, String order, String limit)
    {
        String sql = String.format(sqlSelect, columns, where, order, limit);

        System.out.println(sql);

        return this.RunSelect(sql);
    }

}
```

**Try use it (Result Set to jTable using net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils):**

```
Customers customers = new Customers();

        String customersColumns = "*";
        String customersWhere = "";
        String customersOrder = "";
        String customersLimit = "";

        ResultSet dsCustomers = customers.select(customersColumns, customersWhere, customersOrder, customersLimit);

        this.jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(dsCustomers));
```

**Error:**

```
run:
SELECT * FROM customers   
java.sql.SQLException: The prepared statement has been finalized
    at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.throwex(NativeDB.java:471)
    at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.column_name_utf8(Native Method)
    at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.column_name(NativeDB.java:232)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3ResultSet.getColumnName(JDBC3ResultSet.java:721)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3ResultSet.getColumnLabel(JDBC3ResultSet.java:714)
    at net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(DbUtils.java:21)
    at Frames.MiraReal.seederCustomers(MiraReal.java:142)
    at Frames.MiraReal.<init>(MiraReal.java:37)
    at Frames.MiraReal$2.run(MiraReal.java:177)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Frames.MiraReal.seederCustomers(MiraReal.java:142)
    at Frames.MiraReal.<init>(MiraReal.java:37)
    at Frames.MiraReal$2.run(MiraReal.java:177)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
CONSTRUÍDO COM SUCESSO (tempo total: 2 segundos)
```

What i do?

Thank You!

Comment: That is not how you write a PreparedStatement. I have no Idea what the "%s" is for. When using a PreparedStatement you use "?" set up parameters. then you use the setXXX(...) statement to provide values for those parameters. `I Search in Google and StackOverFlow` - well you need to search again, because there are plenty of examples showing the proper way to use a PreparedStatement. Just use "PreparedStatement" as the search keyword and I'm sure you will find examples.

Comment: I use %s in Actions Layer... This not Used in PreparedStatement! I Delivery it Ready to Database Layer (RunSelect)! Is possible make a Select Query Withou PreparedStatement?

Comment: A PreparedStatment makes it easier to create the SQL statement so you have fewer syntax errors by using incorrect delimiters etc.

Comment: Why do you do anything to not answer the question? if you do not know or do not want to help, you do not have to waste your time disturbing! Thank you for nothing, friend!

Comment: I saw an error message `prepared statement has been finalized`. I have never seen that message before so I didn't know exactly what it was. However when I looked at your code I noticed you were NOT using a `PreparedStatement` properly, so the first suggestion is to obviously fix the statement and see if that helps. This was presented as a comment, not an answer to give you something to think about. Its too bad you don't appreciate the effort people make.

Answer (score 0):

Please re-read carefully the Javadoc for `Statement` (superclass of `PreparedStatement`).

> Note:When a Statement object is closed, its current ResultSet object, if one exists, is also closed.

What is happening is that the `PreparedStatement` is declared in `RunQuery`, and it goes out of scope when that method ends, at which point the `ResultSet` is no longer valid.

You cannot structure the code as you currently have it. The `PreparedStatement` must be defined in the execution scope where the `ResultSet` is used.

Comment: The RunSelect need Return a List with the Select (customers)... With or Without Statement, With or Without Result Set... I need Prepare a List and Insert in This List the contente of ResultSet and then i return the list? how i make it? someone can help me?

Comment: It is Possible in JavaSE?